# Ebean batch not working

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

we have some trouble to get batch insert working with Ebean. We have a collection of objects to persist (about 100) and our database in on a remote area with a lots of latency.

We need to send the insert with one request. I have tried to do that with the following code.

```
Transaction transaction =  Ebean.beginTransaction();
try {
    transaction.setBatchMode(true);

    // Use JDBC batch API with a batch size of 100
    transaction.setBatchSize(100);
    // Don't bother getting generated keys
    transaction.setBatchGetGeneratedKeys(false);
    // Skip cascading persist
    transaction.setPersistCascade(false);

    entity.getList().forEach(Ebean::save);

    transaction.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    System.out.print(ex);
} finally {
    transaction.end();
}
```

It seems to work but actually the TCP dump show that one statement is sent by object so we have about 100 exchanges and it is slow.

Thanks

Comment: What Ebean version are you using? What does Ebean's SQL log look like?  What DB are you using?  What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?